# New-ExoPSSession : unknown_user_type: Unknown User Type

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

## Connect to Exchange 365 using PowerShell to setup DKIM for custom domains

I am super frustrated with Office 365 setting up DKIM for a bunch of custom domains.
I am required to login to the Exchange system using PowerShell and do some voodoo using syntax only Microsoft can invent.

Those are my resources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#install-and-maintain-the-exo-v2-module

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps

### Install dependencie

```
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -RequiredVersion 2.0.3
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
```

I answered Yes to all questions and this seemed to work.

### Logging in

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
```

I am getting asked for my admin credentials and I enter them in the form `user@cortoso.onmicrosoft.com` and I also tried `user@customdomain.com`. **Both work** when I login to Exchange admin via Microsoft web portal.

The next command fails:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $UserCredential -ShowProgress $true -ExchangeEnvironmentName O365GermanyCloud

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
The module allows access to all existing remote PowerShell (V1) cmdlets in addition to the 9 new, faster, and more reliable cmdlets.

|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    Old Cmdlets                    |    New/Reliable/Faster Cmdlets       |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    Get-CASMailbox                 |    Get-EXOCASMailbox                 |
|    Get-Mailbox                    |    Get-EXOMailbox                    |
|    Get-MailboxFolderPermission    |    Get-EXOMailboxFolderPermission    |
|    Get-MailboxFolderStatistics    |    Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics    |
|    Get-MailboxPermission          |    Get-EXOMailboxPermission          |
|    Get-MailboxStatistics          |    Get-EXOMailboxStatistics          |
|    Get-MobileDeviceStatistics     |    Get-EXOMobileDeviceStatistics     |
|    Get-Recipient                  |    Get-EXORecipient                  |
|    Get-RecipientPermission        |    Get-EXORecipientPermission        |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|

To get additional information, run: Get-Help Connect-ExchangeOnline or check https://aka.ms/exops-docs

Send your product improvement suggestions and feedback to <cut>. For issues related to the module, contact Microsoft support. Don't use the feedback alias for problems or support issues.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

New-ExoPSSession : unknown_user_type: Unknown User Type.
In C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ExchangeOnlineManagement\2.0.3\ExchangeOnlineManagement.psm1:426 Zeichen:30
+ ... PSSession = New-ExoPSSession -ExchangeEnvironmentName $ExchangeEnviro ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-ExoPSSession], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellSnapin.NewExoPSSession
```

How can I proceed to login to Exchange in order to setup DKIM keys?

Answer (score 1):

Command works without `ExchangeEnvironmentName`:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $UserCredential -ShowProgress $true
```

And the required user was `user@customdomain.com`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my account has enable MFA. So the command that works is:

Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName navin@contoso.com -ShowProgress $true

replace your user name, and expect to authenticate with Microsoft authenticator.